# Django Rest Framework, display data from a table referenced with a foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I got stuck a bit with a small problem when doing my school project, the problem is that I have an api with DRF and wanting to show my patient data "main table" shows them without problems but when I want to show other patient data in a different table (this table is this reference with a foreign key to Patient) I have not managed to obtain the patient data from this other table.

I can not make my api send me the other patient data from the foreign key referenced to the patient, could you help me?

models.py

```
class Paciente(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    udi = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    first_name = models.CharField('Nombre(s)', max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField('Apellidos', max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField('Sexo', max_length=20, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    birth_day = models.DateField('Fecha de nacimiento', blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField('Número de telefono', max_length=13)
    civil_status = models.CharField('Estado civil', max_length=20, choices=CIVIL_STATUS_CHOICES)
    etc.....

class Antecedentes(TimeStampedModel):
    """
    Modelo de motivo y antecedentes de la enfermedad presentada en el momento de
    la consulta
    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    paciente = models.ForeignKey(Paciente, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    motivo = models.TextField('Motivo de la consulta')
    antecedentes = models.TextField('Antecedentes de la enfermedad actual', blank=True, null=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class antecedenteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="user.username")

    class Meta:
        model = Antecedentes
        fields = ('paciente' ,'motivo', 'antecedentes', )
```

views.py
I was trying this but I'm not if this is correct or not

```
from historiaClinica import models as modelsHC
class antecedenteList(APIView):
    """
    Lista todos los antecedentes o crea uno nuevo
    """
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            paciente = get_object_or_404(pk=pk)
            return modelsHC.Antecedentes.objects.get(paciente=paciente)
        except modelsHC.Antecedentes.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        antecedente = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = antecedenteSerializer(antecedente)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to show all `Antecedentes` related to the specific `Paciente` you can use reverse lookup `paciente.antecedentes_set.all()` so in view you can do this:

```
class antecedenteList(APIView):
    """
    Lista todos los antecedentes o crea uno nuevo
    """
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            paciente = get_object_or_404(pk=pk)
            return paciente
        except modelsHC.Antecedentes.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        paciente = self.get_object(pk)
        antecedentes = paciente.antecedentes_set.all()
        serializer = antecedenteSerializer(antecedentes, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Note I am using serializer's `many=True` argument to serialize multipe objects at the same time.

Also you may need in the future nested serialization to show all `antecedentes` in the `paciente` data. Details of nested serialization you can find [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).

Comment: And the url is the same or change? and thanks for your answer!

Comment: @MiguelToledano I think it would be more restful if you use for this view url like this paciente/{id}/antecedentes: `r'^paciente/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/antecedentes/$'`